# Iterate through Object keys and manipulate the key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects which is coming from server response.

Array structure:

```
[
  {
    col1: ["a", "b"],
    col2: ["c", "d"]
  },

  {
    col1: ["e", "f"],
    col2: ["g", "h"]
  }
]
```

I want the desired output array to be in this form:

```
[
  {
    col1: "b",
    col2: "d"
  },

  {
    col1: "f",
    col2: "h"
  }
]
```

Basically I want to convert the Object keys Value which is an array initially to a single value and that value will be second element of the Object keys array.

I am able to do the conversion by converting Object Keys array to comma seperated string using `toString()`, then do `string.split(",")[1]` but I am not able to iterate through the Object keys.

Would prefer the inputs in ES6 using map for iteration

Comment: This can be achieved using simple loops, Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I am using es6 , using map for looping.  I tried double map but countn't iterate in an optmised way.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) with an inner mapping of a new object with the wanted key/value.

```js
var data = [{ col1: ["a", "b"], col2: ["c", "d"] }, { col1: ["e", "f"], col2: ["g", "h"] }],
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(o).map(k => ({ [k]: o[k][1] }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work as per your specification.

```js
var arr = [ {col1: ["a","b"], col2: ["c","d"] }, {col1: ["e","f"], col2: ["g","h"] } ]


// [ {col1: "b" , col2: "d" }, {col1: "f", col2: "h" } ]

arr2 = [];

arr.forEach(e => {
  let currObj = {};
  Object.keys(e).forEach(f => {
    currObj[f] = e[f][1]
  })
  arr2.push(currObj)
})

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Key names are variable , not fixed as it is coming from server response.

Comment: Works great. Keep it up !

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using `Array#reduce` and `Object.keys`.

```js
var arr = [ {col1: ["a","b"], col2: ["c","d"] }, {col1: ["e","f"], col2: ["g","h"] } ],
    res = arr.reduce(function(s,a) {
      var obj = {};
      Object.keys(a).map(function(c) {
        obj[c] = a[c][1];
      })
      s.push(obj);
      return s;
    }, []);
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Works like a charm.